# Shell scripts run one after another

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell

I have 5 shell scripts. Each has a `java` command. Previous jobs output is input to the next job.

I created a `superScript.sh`

```
//mail - to inform beginning
sh script1.sh;
sh script2.sh;
sh script3.sh;
sh script4.sh;
sh script5.sh;
//mail to inform end
```

Sample `script1.sh`

```
cd toBaseDirectory;
java -cp /path/to/application.jar main.class parameter
```

But all the jobs are started at the same time. How can I make this sequential?

Comment: *But all the jobs are started at the same time.* That doesn't seem possible unless the java program forks itself and runs at the backgorund while the foreground one terminates.

Comment: just one way to send output of bash script execution to another bash script as input `retval=$(./abc.sh) && result=$(./pqr.sh "$retval") && echo "$result"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to run javas like this

```
java -cp /path/to/application.jar main.class parameter & wait
```

Comment: What difference does it make?

Answer (score 0):

If want to run the second command only if the first exited successfully. To do so, join them with &&

`command1 && command2`

simple Example

```
~$ cat abc.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "hi"

~$ cat pqr.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "batman say :  $1"
```

If abc.sh execute successfully then only execute pqr.sh

```
~$ retval=$(./abc.sh) && result=$(./pqr.sh "$retval") && echo "$result"
batman say :  hi
```

you can also try similar approach with your java command execution using shell script

Note:
To execute Shell scripts as command sequentially, waiting for the first to finish before the next one starts. You can use ;
`command1; command2`

Answer (score 0):

`wait` waits for a process to finish

You can also choose to run the second command only if the first exited successfully. To do so, join them with `&&`

```
cmd1 && cmd2
```

but In repetitive cases like this I recommended using a simple loop in the body of your script:

```
for n in {1..5} ; do sh script${n}.sh ; done
```

The loop not only to run them in order but is easier to tweak and reuse when needed, with using brace expansion